# Integration over maximum of absolute value involving random variables

Tags: definite-integrals, random-variables, uniform-distribution

$$ I = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \text{Max}(|(x_1-x_2)(y_1-y_2)|,|(x_2-x_3)(y_2-y_3)|,|(x_3-x_1)(y_3-y_1)|) \ dx_1 \ dy_1 \ dx_2 \ dy_2 \ dx_3 \ dy_1$$

I am trying to find the exact value of this integration. I started with a bit simpler ones.

$$ I_1=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} |x_1-y_1|\ dx_1 \ dy_1=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$ I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \text{Max}(|(x_1-y_1)|,|(x_2-y_2)|)\ dx_1 \ dy_1 \ dx_2 \ dy_2=\frac{7}{15}$$

Using Mathematica I got
$$ I_3=\int_0^1....\int_0^1 \text{Max}(|(x_1-y_1)|,|(x_2-y_2)|,|(x_3-y_3)|)\ dx_1 \ dy_1 \ dx_2 \ dy_2 \ dx_3 \ dy_3=\frac{19}{35}$$

$I_1$ and $I_2$ can be calculated by carefully setting the limits of the variables. But this method is too complicated for solving $I$. Is there any approch to evaluate it? Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: $$I_n=\int_0^1....\int_0^1 \text{Max}(|(x_1-y_1)|,...,|(x_i-y_i)|)\ dx_1 \ dy_1 ... \ dx_n \ dy_n=2^{2n+1}n\left(\text{B}\left(\frac{1}{2};n+1,n\right)-2\text{B}\left(\frac{1}{2};n+2,n\right)\right)$$
where $\text{B}(x;a,b)$ is the incomplete beta function.

In the original question, $I$ is integration over maximum of the pairwise product of difference of two variables.

Comment: Your statement is confusing.  For $I$, you have $Max(x_i-x_j)(y_i-y_j)|$ while for $I_2$ you have $Max(x_i-y_i)(x_j-y_j)|$.  Which is it?

Comment: Does not really matter. You can interchange the variables wlog.

Comment: Try changes of variables $u_i=x_i-y_i$ and $v_i=x_i+y_i$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg, can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: The change of variables simplifies the integration by cutting the number of arguments for integration in half.  For each pair of $(x_i,y_i)$ the integration domain gets rotated by $45^o$ so it consists of two isosceles  right triangles, and symmetry allows you to drop one and multiply by two.

Comment: You are introducing $(u_i,v_i)$ in place of $(x_i,y_i)$. It changes the domain of integration. But how does it cut the number of variables into half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change of variables:  Let $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y$.  $\int_0^1\int_0^1f(|x-y|)dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1 f(|u|)\int_{|u|}^{2-|u|}dvdu=\int_0^1f(u)(2-2u)du$.

Apply to your question: Let $M=max(u_1,...,u_n)$.

$I_n=\int_0^1....\int_0^1 M\prod_{k=0}^n (2-2u_k)du_k$

The domain of integration can be divided into $n$ parts, where in each part $M=u_k$.  Let $J_k$ be the integral over the $k^{th}$ part.  Then $J_k=\int_0^1u_k(2-2u_k)(\prod_{j\ne k} \int_0^{u_k}(2-2u_j)du_j )du_k=\int_0^1 u_k(2-2u_k)(2u_k-u_k^2)^{n-1}du_k$.

Since all $J_k$ are equal, $I_n=n\int_0^1 u(2-2u)(2u-u^2)^{n-1}du$

Comment: Note:  I checked for n=1 and n=2.  Answers agree.

Comment: Thank you so much. My original question was different ($I$ in the question is different from $I_n$). But I guess this approach can be used to solve that. Will give it a try.